# How do I disable HTTPS redirect in Azure DevOps Server 2019 upd 1.1?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

When installing Azure DevOps Server 2019 upd 1.1 with default settings (minus database coupling of course), the system is setup with a self signed SSL certificate and HTTPS redirection.

This is to be published using a reverse SSL/TLS-proxy server with a live certificate. However, in this case, I need to disable the HTTPS requirements on my Azure DevOps Server 2019 upd 1.1 setup.

There is no setting available in the Azure DevOps Server Administration Console for disabling SSL redirect.
Is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: I'd sure like to know how to improve the question, but I've received -1 without any suggestion about how to go about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for all the suggestions.

Unfortunately, I never got the time to set up a TST environment before migrating to Azure DevOps Server 2022.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the public URL in Administration Console. Here are the steps:

1. Open your IIS manager
2. Add site bindings:
   [image]
3. Change Public URL in Administration Console:
   [image]
4. Open your IIS and set the value of sslOnly to false in application settings:
   [image]

Comment: It doesn't fix ssl redirect and breaks ssl access...
Disabling only sslOnly doesn't break anything, but it doesn't remove ssl redirect.

Comment: @Dennis Can you try the steps provided by Vladimir Khvostov in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/715681/redirection-issue-in-tfs.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I will ned to set up a new test environment.
I'm not comfortable with messing around with the DB in production :/

Comment: Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help.

Comment: I'll check back in a week or two. Has some more urging matters at the moment :/

Comment: It's ok. I will wait for your reply.